# Regex Match - How to match a string that does not contain a specific char

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex expression that will match a word (or anything splitted by space) that does not contain a specific character.

For example: `foo anot%her bar idk%what @IJ#N`, I need to match a word does noot contain `%` character, the result is `foo`, `bar` and `@IJ#N`.

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: Question: Would a valid match be a word with some symbol _other_ than `%`, e.g. `idk#what` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes. For example, `foo idk#what ~)JU#I#)` all should be match, although it's not a valid word. Any word (or anything splitted by space) should not be match as long as it contains `%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a word boundary and an anchor at the end, you can write the pattern using lookarounds if those are supported and then match any non whitespace character except for the `%` using a negated character class:

```
(?<!\S)[^\s%]+(?!\S)
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rums02/1)

Answer (score 1):

Since your words contain symbols, you can't use `\w` and `\b` here. `\S` Matches anything other than a space, tab or newline. Negative Lookahead `(?!\S*%\S*)` ensures that `%` is not contained in the string. Finally, add the anchors `^` and `$`. The pattern is `^(?!\S*%\S*)\S+$`, see https://regex101.com/r/DjZFZj/1. If your string is a long string separated by white spaces, just change the boundary. You can change `^` to `(?<=^|\s)` and delete the `$`, the pattern is `(?<=^|\s)(?!\S*%\S*)\S+`, see https://regex101.com/r/0rBhF2/1.